# Chrome rendering differently when content served in ASP.Net Release Mode?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I am running into a problem that is quite grating to my patience and I hope I can get some help or pointers from Stack Overflow.

I have a ASP.Net site hosting a SPA. I used the Bundle feature to serve both javascript and content. I send down the HTML5 doc type, I send down the meta http-equiv to force IE to render in standards mode.    `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Development has been great. However, we recently started building the site in Release mode. IE9 renders both our Debug and Release version in the same way, even after script and style minification and bundling. However, Chrome is not. I'm using Chrome 39 (and my team mate is using 38) and we're both running into the same layout problems. In general, it almost feels as if inline/inline block items are treated differently and Chrome is adding extra white space in certain spots? But why would this only be a problem for Chrome? And only in release mode?

I broke down the bundles and server up the full JS/CSS in both release/debug mode to be sure that the same JS/CSS is coming down. Same problem!

Any ideas? I'm losing it here.

Comment: What are you using client-side?

Comment: An array of libraries ranging from moment to ember to jquery to bootstrap to fancy tree to high charts. Fairly large app.

Comment: What template engine do you use? I had similar problems with handlebars

Comment: Wow, Ok. So I was compiling the templates in Release mode. I disabled this and just append them into the main html and the issue is gone! I guess the compiled templates are wrong. @VsevolodGoloviznin, did you have a fix for this in any way?

Comment: I've posted a possible fix in the answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues when using handlebars in Node.js, but I think it may apply to you as well.

When defining values inside handlebars template remove the spaces between opening/closing tags and handlebars variable.

Instead of this:

```
<div>
    {{youVar}}
</div>
```

Use this:

```
<div>{{yourVar}}</div>
```